# What do you call a person who funds and supports someone else during a certain period of time?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example: Friedrich Engels supported Karl Marx during his entire life, so he could focus on his work. I know there is a word for such a relationship, but cannot remember it. Please help me out.

Comment: The word is *patron*. As in *patron of the arts* or the crowdfunding site *Patreon*.

Comment: Another word for it is *sponsor*.

Comment: Another is benefactor.

Comment: Informally, "angel".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**patron**

> a person who supports with money, gifts, efforts, or endorsement an
>   artist, writer, museum, cause, charity, institution, special event, or
>   the like

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/patron?s=t

Also:  **benefactor, supporter, sponsor, backer, protector**

Answer (score 0):

meacenas / mecenas

generous benefactor, typically a patron in literature or art.

This seems to be rarely used in English, but we do use it in Dutch (it's derived from the Latin word 'mecenas').

Comment: This would be a great answer on Dutch.SE, but I heartily recommend the OP to not use it in English.

Comment: even if it's rarely used?

Comment: Define 'rare'. Why use a barely recognizable word to the vast majority of readers when a much more common word, 'patron' already exists? In certain academic circles (mostly classics) 'maecenas' would be perfectly fine, but outside of that would be pretentious at best.

Comment: ok - agreed - fine with me :) I wasn't sure if people visiting a site like this like it (or not) to come across these rare (possibly pretentious :)) words..

Comment: at Thieme: oh sure, we're totally into rare pretentious words. Where else can you go for that? I'm just adding the nuance about it so that people who read this and have never heard the term before have an idea of really how it is used. In English it is more often used as the proper name of Horace's patron rather than metaphorically as a patron in general.